# Hint the C compiler (GCC or Clang) of possible variable value/range

Tags: c, gcc, clang, llvm

In the following code, only one comparison will be done, because the compiler knows the conditions are exclusive and we will always enter the second condition as `bar` will be necessary > 32:

```
int foo(int bar) {
    if (bar <= 64)
        return 1;
    if (bar > 32) {
        printf("Too many elements");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, imagine I know `bar` is always higher than 64. Because of the input of the system, configuration, or else. How can I hint the compiler to do no comparison at all, like if the `if (bar <= 64) return` was compiled, except it actually isn't kept in the final ASM.

Something like:

```
int foo(int bar) {
    @precond(bar > 64);
    if (bar > 32) {
        printf("Too many elements");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is my only solution to write eg a LLVM pass?

Comment: What for? IMO X-Y problem.

Comment: I don't think the specifics are needed here, it's for high-speed networking optimization. Specializing code according to the predicted input. I slightly changed the problem to make it more clear and state the input.

Comment: I think you can use GCC's `__builtin_expect`: http://blog.man7.org/2012/10/how-much-do-builtinexpect-likely-and.html

Comment: Thanks @ForceBru but that is only a hint, and will keep the branch. It will just ensure that the most probable code is not on the jumped path. I want to remove the jump part. I would like __builtin_enforced maybe :p

Comment: Note that writing a pass is really, really simple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `__builtin_unreachable` in GCC:

```
if (bar > 32) {
  __builtin_unreachable();
}
```

`__builtin_assume` in Clang:

```
__builtin_assume(bar <= 32);
```

and `__assume` in MSVC:

```
__assume(bar <= 32);
```

With C++23 you could also use portable syntax

```
[[assume(bar <= 32)]];
```

Comment: Yes, it works! I verified with gcc -S and there is not any comparison anymore.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but your two examples seem like opposites: the GCC example is declaring that `bar <= 32` is *false*, while the MSVC example is declaring that `bar <= 32` is *true*. No?

Comment: @ruakh Yikes! Fixed.

Comment: In clang you should use `__builtin_assume`, even though `__builtin_unreachable` is available - the latter won't cause the optimiser to omit code, but the former will.

Comment: @user7761803 I have seen `__builtin_unreachable` on clang result in omitted code. IMO, `__builtin_assume(Cond)` should be equivalent to `do if(!(Cond)) __builtin_unreachable(); while(0)`